# merge in oracle comparing dates

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, data-warehouse

I wish to pass FromDate and ToDate into a procedure and then update and insert values as follows.  The `student` and `studLoad` table have 3 fields each: id, name, and insertDate.

```
create or replace procedure incload(f_date date,t_date date) is
begin
    merge into studload sl
    using student s
        on (s.studid=sl.studid)
    when matched then
        update set sl.studname=s.studname, sl.insertdate= trunc(sysdate);
    when not matched then
        insert (sl.studid,sl.studname,sl.insertdate)
        values (s.studid,s.studname,trunc(sysdate)) 
        where s.insertdate > f_date;
end;
```

The date thing is giving me trouble. Where am i going wrong?

***edited to include the error***

```
 ERROR at line 12: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" 

1. create or replace procedure incLoad(f_date date,t_date date) is
2. begin
3. merge into studLoad sl
```

Comment: What "date thing" in particular are you experiencing trouble with?

Comment: when i remove the sl.insertdate= trunc(sysdate) and trunc(sysdate) in the code, the procedure gets created (but ofcourse it doesnt meet my requirements)

Comment: In general, if you are getting an error, it is extremely helpful to post the error rather than making us guess.  I'm assuming that you're getting a compilation error because you are trying to specify a `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT ... VALUES` statement which is not valid syntax.  It would also be helpful to explain exactly what your requirements are-- we have no idea what you would consider to be "correct".

Comment: ah my mistake, please review my edited post to know the error. its not with the where clause, its with the date part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got my mistake- ; was not needed after update i.e., the correct code is:

```
 create or replace procedure incLoad(f_date date,t_date date) is
begin
merge into studLoad sl
using student s
on (s.studID=sl.studID)
when matched then
update set sl.studName=s.studName, sl.insertDate=trunc(sysdate) where s.insertDate > f_date  // no semi-colon
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
INSERT (sl.studID,sl.studName,sl.insertDate)
VALUES (s.studID,s.studName,trunc(sysdate)) where s.insertDate > f_date;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Enclose the where in brackets like

```
where (s.insertdate>f_date);
```

Comment: This does nothing to fix the OP's error. Parentheses around an expression are purely optional...

Comment: @NWest- Parentheses are optional but not wrong! and does not justify your down voting the response (unless you are a designated Oracle Police here on SO)

Comment: The error the OP encountered is `ERROR at line 12: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"`. How does adding parenthesis answer the OP's question? It simply introduces confusion to someone who may just be learning the language.

Comment: We were trying to debug the problem (along with the OP). The query is all fine and as per the error it was obvious that there was a symbol missing somewhere and hence I was trying to resolve this. I don't know why it would confuse someone (and moreover it is a structured way of writing a code, which would be more readable). Also, FYI- I did not say that the "Answer here will solve your problem" in my answer. Lets just say that you wanted to downvote the post and call it a day.